# HTML select tags + JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several `select` tags. What I want to do is, if in one of them let's say option one is selected, option one to be disabled in the other `select`. I have to following code snippet, but it seems like nothing works, or I have inserted it wrongly, or there is something that does not match?

```js
var $selects = $('select');
$selects.on('change', function() {
  $("option", $selects).prop("disabled", false);
  $selects.each(function() {
    var $select = $(this),
      $options = $selects.not($select).find('option'),
      selectedText = $select.children('option:selected').text();
    $options.each(function() {
      if ($(this).text() == selectedText) $(this).prop("disabled",
        true);
    });
  });
});

$selects.eq(0).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="option" size="1" style="width:80px;" required>
  <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Rank</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<br />

<select name="option" size="1" style="width:80px;" required>
  <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Rank</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Your code is actually working.

Comment: it is already working. what is issue in this?

Comment: I think you didn't realize the missing of importing jQuery assets.

Answer (score 0):

Use attr function instead of prop function.

```
$(this).attr("disabled", true);
```